# Sharepoint to replace a fileshare

Tags: sharepoint, filesystems, storage

Is Sharepoint my best option to replace an aging network of fileshares? There's approx 1TB of data residing among 3 fileshares (1 DFS, 2 NAS boxes). A document management system is in place for new things - the file shares are now just read-only archives/legacy. Our users would simply need to be able to search for and open the documents.

Users are finding it difficult to locate their documents in the file shares and windows search does not often help. Sharepoint was suggested as something which would play nicely with Office documents (99% of the content) and have a good search facility.

Not being a Sharepoint Developer or having had any training on it, I'm getting a little lost. I have set up a test server to try it out using SP2013. I have managed to index each of my file shares and have created a search page. However, results aren't consistent with the indexted items. I assume I need to somehow get the relevant metadata from the files but I have no idea how to go about this.

Could anyone suggest some resources for help on this subject (my searches have mainly turned up paid-for Sharepoint addons or outdated blogs) and any experience of doing something similar? Also happy for any suggestions on ways to achieve this using other software/platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with Microsoft Search Server 2010 in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint is basically optimized to be a document manager. I think you don't need to buy or donwload addons.

For your problem, metadata are the key! You need to properly specify the metadata. 
I give you the theory of a plan document management in SharePoint 2013 :

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263266.aspx

A nice introduction to metadata :

http://fr.slideshare.net/gzelfond/document-management-in-sharepoint-without-folders-introduction-to-metadata

Be careful to use the Microsoft documentation for the beginning. From my experience, its difficult to start with this documentation because you have several things in it. There is also good books/ebooks that you can find easily to start well, and probably more simplified than MS documentation.

Comment: The problem with metadata is that there are approx 800,000 existing documents which need to be indexed. Manually adding metadata is simply not an option! I've implemented a search server 2010 setup which seems to be working ok but seems quite limited.